# Many compile errors - Windows Phone SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone

This is my first shot at programming.  Never had any experience, so bear with my slim knowledge on the subject.  I am making an application for Windows Phone that will connect to a user-defined IP Security Camera.  I am getting these errors:

```
Error       1      The name 'box1' does not exist in the current contex
```

The last error happens for all the box1/2/3/4

Here is my code (MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace SecurityCamera
{

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage();
        {
             InitializeComponent();
             defaultPicker.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { {box1.Text}, {box2.Text}, {box3.Text}, {box4.Text} };
        }
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }



       /// <summary>
       /// Go button clicked event handler
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="sender"></param>
       /// <param name="e"></param>
       private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
       }

    }
```

XAML:

```
 x:Class="SecurityCamera.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Security Camera Access" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,-28,96,616">
                <toolkit:ListPicker ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"  Header="Specify IP:" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="defaultPicker" Height="687"/>


            </StackPanel>
            <Button Content="New..." Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,10,0,0" x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Click="button1_Click" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.612,1.036" />
            <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="595" Margin="0,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Pg2 XAML:

```
x:Class="SecurityCamera.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="Security Camera Access" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Add New IP's" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="box1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="31,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="box2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="31,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Box3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="31,150,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="box4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="31,225,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="61,300,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="IMPORTANT: Include http:// before all IP addresses!" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
            <Button Content="Done" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="84,406,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="305" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I find this very weird, as my code wasn't getting these errors before, and I haven't touched a thing (that I know of).

Answer (score 2):

Problem #1 is this:

```
// Constructor
    public MainPage();
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         defaultPicker.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { {box1.Text}, {box2.Text}, {box3.Text}, {box4.Text} };
    }
```

Constructor syntax does not have a semicolon after the name, it should be this instead:

```
// Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         defaultPicker.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { {box1.Text}, {box2.Text}, {box3.Text}, {box4.Text} };
    }
```

Comment: When you get `invalid token` compiler errors that is a good clue to look at the syntax in your code, I am surprised that Visual Studio did not indicate this was a problem on that line or the others that followed.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your entire code, you're missing the final brace `}` that closes the `namespace` scope and your constructor shouldn't have a semi-colon after it

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    defaultPicker.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { {box1.Text}, {box2.Text}, {box3.Text}, {box4.Text} };
}
```

**Update based on edited question**

You're getting that error because `box1` is in the `Page1` class but you're trying to access it from `MainPage`. You have to either use the code behind for `Page1` or learn the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) so that you can separate the logic from the UI.

Comment: That got cut off when I posted, it is in my code (I'll edit the post)

Comment: @user2559105 - Then the only issue seems like the semi-colon after your constructor

Comment: Yup, simple mistake.  Also, I'm getting this error: The name 'box1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user2559105 - In your XAML page have you defined a, presumably, TextBox with the name `box1`? `<TextBox x:Name="box1" ..../>`

Comment: Yes, I have the x:name "box1"

Comment: @user2559105 - You'll have to post your XAML (in your main question). I know it sounds weird but try restarting Visual Studio and see if that fixes that issue. I've had an issue once or twice where it wouldn't pick up the XAML object until a restart of VS.

Comment: Restarting VS didnt help - updating main post with XAML now.

Comment: @user2559105 - You're getting that error because `box1` is in the `Page1` class but you're trying to access it from `MainPage`.

Comment: Ok, is there a way that I can access it from MainPage?

Comment: @user2559105 - Why do you want to access that textbox itself from another page? You can either use the page behind of `Page1` or consider learning the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which will allow you to separate your business logic from the UI.

Comment: What do you mean by page behind of Page1? The program will startup to one page with a webbrowser, and a dropdown menu to choose an IP address to connect to, and a 2nd page where the user can input several IP's to be saved into the 1st dropdown menu.

Comment: Each XAML file has a code behind file called XamlPageName.xaml.cs. The code you typed above is `MainPage.xaml.cs`. If you want to access `box1` from the code behind, you need to be using `Page1.xaml.cs`. Think of the XAML as the UI side and the respective `.cs` file the logic of it.